# building a query with kwargs psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm trying to dynamically build a query and execute using psycopg2 package. The query which I have looks like below

```
def get_employees_for_dept(dept_id):
    sql = '''SELECT 
           emp.FirstName,
           emp.LastName,
           dep.DepartmentName
        FROM Employee emp
        JOIN Department dep
        ON
          dp.EmployeeID = emp.Id
        WHERE
          dp.Id = :dept_id''';
return query.execute(sql, dept_id=dept_id)
```

Now my execute method in query script looks like this:

```
def execute(sql, **kwargs):
     with closing(psycopg2.connect(dbname=config.instance().db_name,
                              user=config.instance().db_user,
                              password=config.instance().db_password,
                              host=config.instance().db_host,
                              port=config.instance().db_port)) as conn:
       with closing(conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)) as cursor:
       cursor.execute(sql, **kwargs)
       return cursor.fetchall()
```

Now when I run this code  I get an error

```
cursor.execute(sql, **kwargs)
TypeError: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id'
```

How can I make this work, without doing a string formatting or string builder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a *tuple* or *dict* as a second parameter to [execute method](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15), not a *list of parameters*.

But when you do `fun(sql, **kwargs)` you actually unrolling container: `fun(sql, a=5, b="ten", ...)`

Here is tiny example:

```
def add_row(*args): # takes multiple arguments
    cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO my_table (id, value)
    VALUES (%s, %s)
    """, args) # args is a tuple

my_args = (1, "some")
add_row(*my_args)
add_row(*(1, "some"))
add_row(1, "some")


def add_row(**kwargs): # takes multiple arguments
    cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO my_table (id, value)
    VALUES (:a, :b)
    """, kwargs) # kwargs is a dict

my_kwargs = {"a":1, "b":"some"}
add_row(**my_kwargs)
add_row(**{"a":1, "b":"some"})
add_row(a=1, b="some")
```

Read [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) brief about injecting values to sql. Since psycopg2 implements Python Database API Specification, you have to take a look at it more closely.

Comment: add_row(a=1, b="some") how is this different from what I did ? Instead of hardcoding the values, I'm passing whatever the function receives ?

Comment: In your code sample, you have to write `return query.execute(sql, {"dept_id": dept_id})` and  `cursor.execute(sql, kwargs)`